# Change a jPanel Background Color to an RGB Value

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a simple Hello World app that changes a jPanel's background color to a random color when you click a button. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Window extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Window
 */

public int r;
public int g;
public int b;
public int color;
Random colorOut = new Random();

public Window() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    colorPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    colorBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout colorPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(colorPanel);
    colorPanel.setLayout(colorPanelLayout);
    colorPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        colorPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    colorPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        colorPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 204, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    colorBtn.setText("Color!");
    colorBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            colorBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitBtn.setText("Exit :(");
    exitBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitBtnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(colorPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(colorBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(exitBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(colorPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(colorBtn)
                .addComponent(exitBtn))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void colorBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    color = colorOut.nextInt(9) + 1;

    switch (color) {
        case 1:
            r = 255;
            g = 17;
            b = 17;
            break;
        case 2:
            r = 255;
            g = 151;
            b = 17;
            break;
        case 3:
            r = 255;
            g = 255;
            b = 17;
            break;
        case 4:
            r = 17;
            g = 255;
            b = 100;
            break;
        case 5:
            r = 10;
            g = 120;
            b = 50;
            break;
        case 6:
            r = 20;
            g = 160;
            b = 255;
            break;
        case 7:
            r = 25;
            g = 20;
            b = 255;
            break;
        case 8:
            r = 240;
            g = 20;
            b = 255;
            break;
        case 9:
            r = 110;
            g = 10;
            b = 120;
            break;
    }


}                                        

private void exitBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(1);
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Window().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton colorBtn;
private javax.swing.JPanel colorPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton exitBtn;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

(Most of the other stuff is just NetBeans code generation.)

**Pay attention to the colorBtnActionPerformed function**

Most of the other questions I've been to have gotten responses to change it like:

```
setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

but I want to set it to a certain RGB value. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look at the possible constructors of the class Color:

```
Color(int rgb)
Color(int r, int g, int b)
Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
Color(float r, float g, float b)
Color(float r, float g, float b, int a)
```

So for the color with the hex code #92f442 you might call

```
setBackground(new Color(0x92f442));
```

or

```
setBackground(new Color(146, 244, 66));
```

or

```
setBackground(new Color(0.57255f, 0.95686f, 0.25882f));
```

So to set the background to a random color I would suggest:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Color col = new Color(rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255),rand.nextInt(255));
setBackground(col);
```

Comment: I get an error saying no suitable method found for setBackground(Color) and yes I did say panelName.setBackground(col)